# How to create custom origin that executes abritrary code on transactions

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, origin, signed-extensions

How can I create a custom origin that executes some arbitrary logic on any transaction? The use case here is some identity check that fails a transaction, if the check fails.

In addition, I want to execute some custom logic on transactions coming from any transactions in my runtime, not just from extrinsics in custom pallets that I maintain.

Is this possible to do using just custom origins?

I am aware of Signed Extensions and their ability to extend transactions. Is there a reason I should not use Signed Extensions for such a case?

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to execute custom logic on all transactions in your system, then a `SignedExtension` is the way to go. It can be used to introduce both new data into your chain's transactions, as well as checks, prioritisation, payment, ordering and more.

Introducing a new Origin is not needed for this, nor could it be used to alter the effective logic of any pallets you are not authoring to recognise this new Origin.